# Python minimax Game tree

Tags: python, python-2.7, artificial-intelligence

I am having problems regarding a specific part of my code.
I am trying to create a game tree for a chess-like game, to use minimax algorithm.
The problem lies in the nested for loops, the game state does not seem to reset each time it exits the nested loop. This results to the game progressing rather than exploring the possible game options.

Things to know:

1. available_moves returns the possible moves given a game state(board) and a player
2. make_move returns a board (2D list) after a given move has been made
3. I track the number of leaf nodes by the leaf_cnt variable
4. The make_move arguments function properly (are tested)

   ```
   def minimax_3 (board,myColor,depth=4):
   board_s = board
   player = myColor
   leaf_cnt = 0

   l=1

   for m1 in available_moves(board_s,l%2):
       board2 = make_move(int(m1[0]), int(m1[1]), int(m1[2]), int(m1[3]), 9, 9, board_s)

       l=2
       for m2 in available_moves(board2, l % 2):

           board3 = make_move(int(m2[0]), int(m2[1]), int(m2[2]), int(m2[3]), 9, 9, board2)

           l = 3
           for m3 in available_moves(board3, l % 2):

               board4 = make_move(int(m3[0]), int(m3[1]), int(m3[2]), int(m3[3]), 9, 9, board3)

               leaf_cnt+=1


   print leaf_cnt
   ```

EDIT: Wrong Way

```
def make_move(x1,y1,x2,y2,px,py,board_o):

board_l = board_o
board_l[x2][y2]=board_l[x1][y1]
board_l[x1][y1]= " "

if px!=9 and py!=9:
    board_l[px][py] = "P"

for i in range(5):
    if board_l[6][i]=="BP":
        board_l[6][i]=" "
    if board_l[0][i] == "WP":
        board_l[0][i] = " "

return board_l
```

Comment: Did you check that the make_move returns actually a new board. Depending on the definition of your make move funktion it is entirely possible that you only have one actual board object that is referenced by multiple variables. posting the make move could help determine if that is the case

Comment: Edited to include make_move

Comment: `board_l = board_o` doesn't make a new board. Assignment doesn't work like that in Python. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Man thank you so much. I feel ashamed for not understanding this, I solved the problem and the program is working flawlessly now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved
Correct Way

```
def make_move(x1,y1,x2,y2,px,py,board_o):
w, h = 5, 7;
board_l = [[board_o[y][x] for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
board_l[x2][y2]=board_l[x1][y1]
board_l[x1][y1]= " "

if px!=9 and py!=9:
    board_l[px][py] = "P"

for i in range(5):
    if board_l[6][i]=="BP":
        board_l[6][i]=" "
    if board_l[0][i] == "WP":
        board_l[0][i] = " "

return board_l
```

Thanks so much @user2357112